# Getting the onclick value without clicking Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I want to access a value on a website where I pull data. This value is a value when clicked on. However, I want to do it without clicking, because there are bot blockers, I should not interact too much. When I press f12, the value appears, but I cannot reach this value because it does not appear on the page. How can I do it.

website's html

```
<div onclick="TextClick(0)"  class="classname">Click and see value</div>
<div id="details" class="Box">
    <label>value</label>
</div>
```

my code bot.py

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import os
browser = webdriver.Chrome()


browser.get('https://www.examplewebsiteinhere.com')
print(browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#Details > label').text)
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you run the JS function TextClick(0) directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print(browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#Details_0 > label').get_attribute("textContent"))
```

Using get_attribute("textContent") can retrieve text not displayed in ui but is available in the dom